# Tracking code history and comparison

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn, simulation

Delphi history is very useful when you need to access prev version of your code. Also has comparison that makes finding changes very easier. But has its main disadvantage, limited number of history.

I thought Tortoise SVN is able to do this, but beside its great setup I realized I can not explore my code history and compare it with another versions.

Q: Do I am wrong or does ToitoiseSVN not for this task?
Q: Is there any other alternative that able to do this task?

Note: I'm not working in a team.

Answer (score 0):

- Yes, you are worong
- Yes, there are alternatives